# Excel 2007 - Rearranging Vertical Data in Horizontal Rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have hundreds of rows data in vertical columns. I want to rearrange it in rows.....

Image is attached what I want to achieve.....

your valuable Help is appreciated...

[image]

Comment: Is the example you've given an extract representation of the structure of data you're dealing with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**A19** = `2`

**A20** = `A19 + 3`

**B19** = `=INDIRECT("A" & $A19)`

**C19** = `=INDIRECT("B" & $A19)`

**D19** = `=INDIRECT("C" & $A19)`

**E19** = `=INDIRECT("C" & $A19 + 1)`

**F19** = `=INDIRECT("C" & $A19 + 2)`

**G19** = `=INDIRECT("D" & $A19)`

**H19** = `=INDIRECT("D" & $A19 + 1)`

**I19** = `=INDIRECT("D" & $A19 + 2)`

**J19** = `=INDIRECT("E" & $A19)`

**K19** = `=INDIRECT("E" & $A19 + 1)`

**L19** = `=INDIRECT("E" & $A19 + 2)`

... now fill down as far as you need but be careful filling down column A from **A19**, you need to fill down from **A20**.

You can make it more dynamic by putting the column letters above your headers if you want but that's up to you.

There are a few ways to do what you want and you may find an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HV4W.png)

Check Above Sample Pic